Playing audio with web audio api
I followed some tutorials to make the audio play automatically when certain conditions are met. However, the audio does not play automatically. Here is my code.
Parts_Request_Display_Servlet.java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        User usr = session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") != null ? (User) session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser") : new User();
        if (!(UserBean.is_supervisor(usr) || UserBean.is_schedule(usr))) {
            response.sendRedirect("/hdi.jsp?err=AccessDenied");
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Parts_Request_Display_Data> slist = new ArrayList<Parts_Request_Display_Data>();
        NumberFormat nfi = NumberFormat.getInstance();

        try {
            slist = new Parts_Request_Display_Beans().GetRequestFormDisplayList();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String tbl = "<div class=\"screen\" style=\"padding:50px;\">" +
                "<table class=\"table\">" +
                "<tr><td colspan=2 class=\"text-left gray2 em3\">Request Status</td><td colspan=4 class=\"text-right\"><div id=\"clockbox\"></div></td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td class=\"text-center white em3 bold\">Req#</td>" +
                "<td class=\"text-left pink em4 bold\">Req Loc</td>" +
                "<td class=\"text-left pink em4 bold\">Requester</td>" +
                "<td class=\"text-center yellow em3 bold\">Status</td>" +
                "<td class=\"text-center white em3 bold\">Req Elap</td>" +
                "<td class=\"text-center white em3 bold\">Ready Elap</td></tr>";

        DateFormat dbDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        long REQ_elapsed = 0;
        String REQ_elapsedTime = "";
        long READY_elapsed = 0;
        String READY_elapsedTime = "";
        int beep = 0;
        String alamPath = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + File.separator + "webapps" + File.separator + "assets" + File.separator + "PartRoom_alam" + File.separator;

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); // Create JSONObject instance

        for (int i = 0; i < slist.size(); i++) {
            Parts_Request_Display_Data dto = slist.get(i);
            String REQ_ID = dto.get_REQ_ID();
            String REQ_LOC = dto.get_REQ_LOC();
            String REQER = dto.get_REQUESTER();
            String STATUS = dto.get_STATUS().trim();
            String REQ_DATE = dto.get_REQ_DATE();
            String READY_DATE = dto.get_READY_DATE();
            int octa_include = dto.get_octa_include(); // Get the octa_include field value
            String audioPath = ""; // Path to the audio file

            String StatusBG = "";
            String ReqLocColor = ""; // Initialize ReqLocColor
            String ReqerColor = "";  // Initialize ReqerColor

            // Check if octa_include is 1
            if (octa_include == 1) {
                ReqLocColor = "style=\"color:yellow;\"";  // Apply yellow color to REQ_LOC
                ReqerColor = "style=\"color:yellow;\"";   // Apply yellow color to REQER
            }

            if (STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("request")) {
                beep++;
                STATUS = "-----";
                READY_elapsedTime = "-----";
                try {
                    REQ_elapsed = DateCalc.getDateDiffMinutes(dbDateformat.parse(REQ_DATE), new Date());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                REQ_elapsedTime = String.format("%5dm", REQ_elapsed);

                // Check if octa_include is 1
                if (octa_include == 1) {
                    audioPath = alamPath + "octa+Request.mp3";
                } else {
                    audioPath = alamPath + "part+Request.mp3";
                }

                // Include the audio path in the JSON response
                json.put("audioPath", audioPath);
            } else if (STATUS.equalsIgnoreCase("ready")) {
                StatusBG = "bg-danger";
                STATUS = "Ready";
                try {
                    REQ_elapsed = DateCalc.getDateDiffMinutes(dbDateformat.parse(REQ_DATE), new Date());
                    READY_elapsed = DateCalc.getDateDiffMinutes(dbDateformat.parse(READY_DATE), new Date());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                REQ_elapsedTime = String.format("%5dm", REQ_elapsed);
                READY_elapsedTime = String.format("%5dm", READY_elapsed);
            }

            tbl += "<tr>";
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-center white em3 bold\">" + REQ_ID + "</td>";
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-left pink em3 bold\" " + ReqLocColor + ">" + REQ_LOC + "</td>";  // Apply yellow color to REQ_LOC if needed
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-left pink em4 bold\" " + ReqerColor + ">" + REQER + "</td>";    // Apply yellow color to REQER if needed
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-center wheat em4 bold " + StatusBG + " \">" + STATUS + "</td>";
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-center white em4 bold \">" + REQ_elapsedTime + "</td>";
            tbl += "<td class=\"text-center white em4 bold \">" + READY_elapsedTime + "</td>";
            tbl += "</tr>";
        }

        tbl += "</table></div>";

        Date curdate = new Date();
        String curtime = "<span class='em2 font-italic purple-100'>" + new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(curdate) + ",</span>"
                + " <span class='em2 font-italic light-green-200'>" + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(curdate) + ",</span>"
                + " <span class='em2 font-italic cyan-100'>" + new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a").format(curdate) + "</span>";

        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=utf-8");

        json.put("textMsg", tbl);
        json.put("timespan", 22000);
        json.put("beep", beep);
        json.put("curtime", curtime);

        try (PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter()) {
            pw.print(json.toString());
        }

Parts_Request_Display_Servlet.jsp
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@page import="java.text.*" %>
<%@page import="java.time.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="hdi.common.*" %>
<jsp:useBean id = "ub" class = "hdi.common.UserBean" scope="page"/>
<jsp:useBean id = "pu" class = "hdi.common.PageUtils" scope="page"/>

<%
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);
//prevents caching at the proxy server
request.setAttribute("hdiUrl", "/");

String pageHREF = request.getRequestURI();
Set<String> roleSet = ub.GetPageRoleSet(pageHREF);

User usr = session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser")!=null ? (User)session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"): new User() ;

if ( UserBean.hasAccessPage(usr, roleSet)){
    UserBean.accessLogged(usr, pageHREF);
}else{
    response.sendRedirect("/hdi.jsp?err=AccessDenied");
    return;
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Parts Request Display</title>
<% out.println(pu.Header()); %>
<style>
.screen,
#slideshow,
#slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1; 
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#0000ff;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='hidden' name='Serial' id='Serial' value='1'>
<div id="slideshow"></div>
<audio id="audioPlayer" preload="auto"></audio> <!-- Audio element for playing sound -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script>

var timespan = 15000;
var beep = 0;
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');

(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/part/Part_Room/Parts_Request_Display/Parts_Request_Display_Servlet', 
        success: function(data) {
            $('#slideshow').html(data.textMsg);
            timespan = parseInt(data.timespan);
            beep = parseInt(data.beep);
            $('#clockbox').html(data.curtime);

            // Check if audioPath is available and play the audio
            if (data.audioPath) {
                audioPlayer.src = data.audioPath;
                audioPlayer.play();
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(worker, timespan);
        }
    });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>


The audio is supposed to play automatically when a request is received, but the audio is not playing.

This is a feature of most modern web browsers. You cannot auto-play sound without the user first interacting with the page, ie. by clicking a button

This question is similar to: Playing a simple sound with web audio api. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
